# how to search all data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I saved scrapy crawling data in elasticsearch. There's hundreds of documents saved in elasticsearch, but only five documents are being displayed in elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch query:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/mall/search/_search?pretty
```

The result of above query:

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 397,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "73f419e9b8b59a60315280a8df765e11bc8fc0ac",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 48,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/2e/dd/122edd2be6.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[MSI] MSI 최강 게이밍 노트북 GP62-7RDX Leopard ultimate</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B439698159&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "1,129,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "6fb57d6ecf908ed00512a0ba1f0ba23cdf2d5615",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 2117,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/10/b9/f4/10b9f41526.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">노트북 XH57 BossMonster Hero456GT 게이밍</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B389377365&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "668,990",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "0a9760b5d349eac8282808d954366f1ec5800c9d",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 3,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/11/34/bb/1134bb9016.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[삼성전자] 삼성 신모델 NT300E5Q-KD5S-7 (i5/SSD120G)win7 비즈</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B407944583&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "799,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "c591cc96b2e4af69b382c328757348410739f873",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 24,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/64/f9/1264f91be6.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[파빌리온] 9월특가+GIFT/i7/GTX1050/NVMe/게이밍 15-bc223TX_LE</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B402800443&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "1,299,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "ca57eab78a65df174c811c9517a28c13dcaf3ae2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 88,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/11/c4/56/11c456a8c6.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">노트북 XF57 BossMonster Lv.61 게이밍</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B391694689&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "658,990",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "ed71876733cccfb2b1327d70d5864835bb7463ec",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "PC서버",
                "count": 9,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/d6/a4/2d/d6a42d016.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[HP] HP 워크스테이션 Z800 Z600</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B261811590&keyword=&Fwc=22250000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "1,200,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "80b19759e945789dd2e9956de22ea4f2c3746d8a",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "PC서버",
                "count": 92,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/b1/f0/78/b1f078a36.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">LS-LS12   랜스타 고급 RJ-45 랜 선택기 1:2 8P8C</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=A980343024&keyword=&Fwc=22250000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "5,770",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "34d1d3cfef1a8e643a3c37f520cb71979d669613",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "노트북",
                "count": 111,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/a4/4a/12a44a5d86.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">최종가71만 사은품 3종 게이밍노트북 HP 15-bc229TX</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B435753012&keyword=&Fwc=22160000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "759,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "026408368c6ef8f8f03a338276c3889d44bd25ac",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "모니터",
                "count": 764,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/12/35/07/1235076f26.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[코리아정보통신] 10 12 19인치 소형/차량용모니터/AV/CCTV/미니/보조</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=A621585384&keyword=&Fwc=01920000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "89,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "mall",
            "_type": "search",
            "_id": "c791966d2cccca86c4c31061a12fc8272127d537",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "category": "모니터",
                "count": 725,
                "img": "http://image.auction.co.kr/itemimage/c5/e4/42/c5e442516.jpg",
                "title": "<h1 class=\"itemtit\">[삼성전자] 삼성 S27B240B LE / 27인치 대화면 풀HD LED모니터</h1>",
                "url": "http://itempage3.auction.co.kr/DetailView.aspx?ItemNo=B231610363&keyword=&Fwc=01920000&scoredtype=0",
                "price": "139,000",
                "site": "auction"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

This result shows total count 397, but only 7 documents are displayed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just a note. I believe you're reading the successful shard count as the doc count, based on your initial question (you're seeing 10 here). The provided answer is correct in saying you need to specify if you want to return more than the 10 (default) response docs

Answer (score 3):

you need to specify size query parameter as the default is 10

```
curl http://localhost:9200/mall/search/_search?size=1000&pretty
```